# Como obter o último dia de um mês com MomentJS?

Tags: javascript, data, momentjs

Estou usando `MomentJS` e preciso pegar o primeiro e último dia do mês atual.

Atualmente, para pegar o primeiro dia do mês estou fazendo assim:

```
 var data_inicial = moment().format('01/MM/YYYY')
```

Até aí tudo bem, já que todo mês começa com `01`.

Mas e no caso do último dia do mês? Como eu posso pegar o último dia do mês com MomentJs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A solução é usar [`endOf('month')`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/), como a sua [própria resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/330634/112052) indica.

Só há um detalhe: este método também altera o horário. Veja no exemplo abaixo:

```js
 console.log(moment([2018, 8, 19]).endOf('month'))
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

*No exemplo acima eu passei `[2018, 8, 19]` como parâmetro para o `moment`, para criar a data de 19 de setembro de 2018 (quando se passa [este array](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/array/), os meses são indexados em zero: janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc, por isso setembro é o mês 8 nesse caso). Se quiser a data atual, basta usar `moment()` sem parâmetros.*

No meu caso, a saída foi `"2018-10-01T02:59:59.999Z"` (sim dia 1 de outubro, bem diferente do esperado - mas já explico).

Isso acontece porque `moment()` usa a data/hora atual (19 de setembro de 2018) e `endOf('month')` muda o dia para o último do mês (30) e o horário para 23:59:59.999, mas sempre usando o **timezone do browser**.

No meu caso, o timezone do browser é `America/Sao_Paulo`, ou seja, a data resultante é `2018-09-30T23:59:59.999-03:00` (30 de setembro de 2018, às 23:59:59.999 em São Paulo - o offset `-03:00` indica que estamos 3 horas atrás de UTC). Convertendo para UTC resulta em `2018-10-01T02:59:59.999Z` (o "Z" no final [indica que está em UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC))).

Ao usarmos [`format()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) é retornada a data correta, porque é usado o timezone do browser para obter os valores de data e hora:

```js
 console.log(moment([2018, 8, 19]).endOf('month').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS'))
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Agora a saída é `30/09/2018 23:59:59.999`. O último dia do mês (30 de setembro) com o horário alterado para 23:59:59.999.

---

Como você só está pegando a data no `format` e ignorando a hora, isso não é um problema.

Mas se quiser manter o mesmo horário, basta criar outro `moment` e setar o horário, usando [`set`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/set/) e passando os valores que você quer alterar (no caso, os campos do horário):

```js
// data e hora atual
var d1 = moment();

// obter o fim do mês e setar horário para o atual
var d2 = moment().endOf('month').set({
    'hour' : d1.get('hour'),
    'minute' : d1.get('minute'),
    'second' : d1.get('second'),
    'millisecond' : d1.get('millisecond')
});

console.log(d1.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS'));
console.log(d2.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS'));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Nesse caso, `d2` terá a data do último dia do mês e o horário será "inalterado" (ou seja, será igual ao horário atual do momento em que o `moment` foi criado).

---

#### Bônus

Para descobrir o timezone do browser, use [Momentjs Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) e a função [`guess()`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/). Ela tem esse nome porque nem sempre é possível saber com precisão o timezone correto (na [documentação](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/) explica melhor).

E para o primeiro dia do mês também é possível usar [`startOf('month')`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/). Mas ele tem uma característica similar a `endOf`, que é mudar o horário para meia-noite.

Comment: Só complementando, outra forma de se ajustar a diferença de horário seria converter para um objeto de data com o `.toDate()` e então usar o `.setHours(-1)`, o que retornaria um objeto de data do ultimo horário do dia anterior (que no caso estava 1 de outubro). Creio que tenha suas vantagens, caso ele não vá usar mais a data como objeto `moment`

Comment: Obrigado pela excelente contribuição. Havia muito tempo que não via  respostas boas e completas assim no site. +1

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o método [`endOf`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/) e adicionar o parâmetro `'month'`.

Exemplo:

```
 moment().endOf('month').format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```