# Date em JavaScript com dia 31 de Outubro

Tags: javascript, data

Estou tentado buscar a data do vencimento somando a data, porém percebi que a função não me retorna o dia 31 de Outubro do ano 2019.

Segue o código abaixo que me retorna '1 / 11 / 2019' e deveria me retornar '31 / 10 / 2019':

```
var data = new Date('2019','10','01');
data.setDate( + 31  ) ;
console.log( data.getDate() + ' / ' + data.getMonth() + ' / ' +data.getFullYear());
```

Comment: Por qual razão a função deveria retornar 31 se você está somando 31 a 1?

Comment: Exato, mas se coloco 30 me retorna '30 / 10 / 2019'.

Answer (score 3):

O problema e como você esta inicializando o [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) note:

```js
var data = new Date('2019','10','01');
console.log( "new Date('2019','10','01')", 'NOVEMBRO', data.toLocaleDateString(), 'getMonth:', data.getMonth() )

var data = new Date('2019','0','01');
console.log( "new Date('2019','0','01')", 'JANEIRO' , data.toLocaleDateString(), 'getMonth:',data.getMonth() );

var data = new Date('2019','09','01');
console.log(  "new Date('2019','09','01')", 'OUTUBRO', data.toLocaleDateString(), 'getMonth:',data.getMonth() )
```

> [`new Date(ano, mês, dia, hora, minuto, segundo, milissegundo);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
>   **Parâmetros para o constructor Date**
>   <sub>Nota: Quando Date for chamado como um construtor com mais de um argumento, se os valores forem maiores do que seu limite lógico (e.g. se 13 for fornecido como um valor para mês ou 70 for o valor para minuto), o valor adjacente será ajustado. E.g. `new Date(2013, 13, 1)` é equivalente a `new Date(2014, 1, 1)`, ambos criam uma data para `2014-02-01` **(note que o mês começa em 0)**. Similarmente para outros valores: `new Date(2013, 2, 1, 0, 70)`é equivalente a `new Date(2013, 2, 1, 1, 10)`, pois ambos criam uma data para 2013-03-01T01:10:00.</sub>
>
> **`ano`**: 
>   Um valor inteiro que representa o ano. Valores de 0 a 99 correspondem aos anos de 1900 a 1999.
>
> **`mês`**: 
>   Um valor inteiro que representa o mês, começando com **0** para Janeiro até **11** para Dezembro.
>   **`dia`**:
>   Um valor inteiro que representa o dia do mês.

Comment: Entendi, o mês inicia com 0 ( zero ).
Obrigado!!!

Answer (score 0):

No [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) do JavaScript, os [meses são indexados em zero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/405994/112052) (janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc). Então `new Date('2019','10','01')` cria uma data referente a 1 de novembro de 2019.

Ao setar o dia para 31, o resultado é 1 de dezembro de 2019 (pois novembro não tem 31 dias, então o valor 31 acaba sofrendo um ajuste para o mês seguinte), e como [`getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) também segue a regra de ser indexado em zero, ele retorna 11, e você acaba tendo como resultado "1/11/2019".

Então bastaria passar o valor 9 para o mês, e somar 1 ao retorno de `getMonth()`:

```js
let data = new Date(2019, 9, 1);
data.setDate(31);
console.log( data.getDate() + ' / ' + (data.getMonth() + 1) + ' / ' + data.getFullYear());
```

Aliás, um detalhe importante: `setDate(+31)` está mudando o dia para 31. **Ele não está somando 31 dias**, e o sinal de mais não faz diferença (`+31` é o mesmo que o número `31`). Prova disso é que a data pode começar em qualquer dia, que o resultado será dia 31:

```js
let data = new Date(2019, 9, 30);
data.setDate(+31);
console.log(`${data.getDate()}/${data.getMonth() + 1}/${data.getFullYear()}`);
```

Mesmo começando com uma data no dia 30, `setDate(+31)` (que é o mesmo que `setDate(31)`) não somou 31 dias, apenas mudou o valor do dia para 31  ([veja a documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate)).

---

Agora se você quer sempre o último dia do mês, independente da data, setar o dia para 31 não vai funcionar para todos os casos (já que alguns meses tem 30 dias, e fevereiro pode ter 28 ou 29). Então o que você pode fazer é criar uma data referente ao primeiro dia do mês seguinte e subtrair 1 dia:

```js
// 1 de novembro de 2019
let d = new Date(2019, 10, 1);
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1); // subtrai 1 dia

// mostra a data no formato dd/mm/yyyy
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR')); // 31/10/2019
// ou, se quiser formatar manualmente
console.log(`${d.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')}/${(d.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')}/${d.getFullYear()}`); // 31/10/2019
```

Repare que os valores passados para o construtor podem ser números em vez de strings (aliás, [é o tipo esperado pelo construtor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Individual_date_and_time_component_values)).

Para formatar a data, fiz de dois jeitos: usando [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString), que usa formatos predefinidos baseado no *locale* (no caso usei `pt-BR`, que corresponde a "português do Brasil", que possui o formato dd/mm/yyyy), e formatando manualmente (usando [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) para completar com zero à esquerda quando o valor é menor que 10).

---

## Moment.js

Outra alternativa é usar o [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com):

```js
// várias maneiras de criar "1 de outubro de 2019"
let d = moment([2019, 9, 1]);
d = moment({ year: 2019, month: 9, day: 1 });
d = moment('2019-10-01'); // nesse caso o mês é 10 mesmo

// último dia do mês
d.endOf('month');
console.log(d.format('DD/MM/YYYY')); // 31/10/2019
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Primeiro eu crio a data, e veja que há varias formas diferentes. As duas primeiras usam a regra do mês indexado em zero, e a terceira usa o valor correto.

Depois eu uso o [método `endOf`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/) para obter o final do mês, e o [método `format`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) para mostrar a data em um formato específico.

Se precisar obter um `Date` do JavaScript, basta fazer [`d.toDate()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/).

Lembrando que `endOf` também muda o horário, conforme explicado em detalhes [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/330660/112052).