# Obter último dia da semana retorna data equivalente a um dia a mais

Tags: javascript, data, date-fns

Para obter o primeiro dia da semana da data 07/10/2020, utilizei a função `startOfWeek` da biblioteca date-fns. Dessa forma, retornou 04/10/2020, o que está certo.

```
const primeiroDiaSemana = startOfWeek(new Date(2020, 9, 7)); // 04/10/2020 certo
```

Mas ao passar essa mesma data para a função `endOfWeek`, para obter o último dia da semana, é retornado a data 11/10/2020 ao invés de 10/10/2020.

```
const ultimoDiaSemana = endOfWeek(new Date(2020, 9, 7)); // 11/10/2020 errado
```

Gostaria de saber por que isso acontece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema não é a data gerada, e sim - provavelmente - a forma como você está mostrando/imprimindo ela.

Usando o seu exemplo e mostrando as datas de 2 maneiras diferentes, temos:

```js
const primeiroDiaSemana = dateFns.startOfWeek(new Date(2020, 9, 7));
const ultimoDiaSemana = dateFns.endOfWeek(new Date(2020, 9, 7));

console.log(primeiroDiaSemana.toString()); // Sun Oct 04 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)
console.log(ultimoDiaSemana.toString());   // Sat Oct 10 2020 23:59:59 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)

// sem toString, imprime em UTC
console.log(primeiroDiaSemana); // 2020-10-04T03:00:00.000Z
console.log(ultimoDiaSemana); // 2020-10-11T02:59:59.999Z
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.min.js"></script>
```

Primeiro eu usei `toString()`, que formata a data de acordo com o timezone (fuso horário) que está configurado no *broswer* (no meu caso, é o Horário de Brasília), e veja que neste caso o resultado está correto (último dia da semana = 10 de outubro de 2020). Só que o horário também mudou, e foi alterado para 23:59:59 (afinal, `endOfWeek` pega o "último instante da semana", então ele não altera apenas o dia).

E esse é o "problema". Se eu só imprimir a data diretamente com `console.log`, o resultado é dependente da implementação: alguns *browsers* podem mostrar o mesmo resultado de `toString`, mas o Node e o *snippet* do site acima mostram a data em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Repare no exemplo acima que a data foi mostrada como `2020-10-11T02:59:59.999Z`: o "Z" no final indica que ela está em UTC, e como 10/10/2020 às 23:59 no Horário de Brasília corresponde a 11/10/2020 às 02:59 em UTC, você acaba tendo a impressão de que a data está "errada". Não está, é apenas a forma de visualização - e o timezone usado para tal - que acabou mudando o resultado final.

---

Isso tudo acontece porque o `Date` do JavaScript na verdade representa um [timestamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052) (um ponto na linha do tempo), não uma data específica (um único valor de dia, mês, ano, hora, minuto e segundo).

Para mais detalhes, leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/456089/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/455437/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/408160/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/416172/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/344030/112052).

Comment: Muito obrigado, hkotsubo! Muito esclarecedor.