# Como pegar o valor de um input type="month" no qual traz mês e ano e separá-lo em duas variáveis (mes e ano)

Tags: javascript, data

Tenho um `input type="month"` no meu HTML, no qual seleciono nesse campo o mês e ano.
Essa informação chega no JavaScript no formato "mm/AAAA" conforme código abaixo:

```
<input type="month" id="month" />
```

No JavaScript, pego o `value` desse `input` conforme trecho abaixo:

```
let datainput = document.getElementById('month').value;
```

O retorno do `datainput` é "09/2022" por exemplo.

Porém, preciso separar o mês e o ano em variáveis diferentes dentro do JavaScript.
Como posso realizar isso?

Comment: `const [mes, ano] = datainput.split('/');`

Comment: `var data = new Date(datainput.value);   data.getMonth() data.getFullYear()`... input retorna uma strg que pode ser passada por parâmetro no Date que retorna inteiro. só o mês que inicia apartir de 0 a 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Essa informação chega no JavaScript no formato "mm/AAAA"*

Tem certeza? Pois segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month) e a [especificação](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#valid-month-string), o `value` de um campo `input type="month"` sempre é uma string no formato "YYYY-MM" (para [browsers que suportam este tipo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month#browser_compatibility), claro).

O que acontece é que **o browser pode mostrar o campo em um formato diferente**. Mas internamente o `value` sempre é "YYYY-MM". Faça o teste, preencha uma data e clique no botão "Mostrar value" (mas teste em um [browser que suporte o tipo `month`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month#browser_compatibility)):

```js
function mostrarValue() {
    console.log(document.getElementById('month').value);
}
```

```html
<input type="month" id="month" />
<button onclick="mostrarValue()">Mostrar value</button>
```

Cada browser vai exibir o campo em um formato diferente. Estou usando Chrome configurado em inglês, então para mim mostra os nomes dos meses em inglês:

[image: git mostrando mês sendo selecionado]

Já no Firefox, atualmente (setembro/2022) ele ainda não suporta este tipo, então só aparece como um `input text` simples (que eu posso digitar qualquer coisa). A [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month#handling_browser_support) cita meios de contornar isso, mas acho que está além do escopo da pergunta.

---

Enfim, para browsers que suportam o `input type="month"`, o `value` sempre estará no formato "YYYY-MM", então uma forma de separar os campos é com um `split` simples:

```js
function separarAnoMes() {
    let [ano, mes] = document.getElementById('month').value.split('-');
    console.log(mes, ano);
}
```

```html
<input type="month" id="month" />
<button onclick="separarAnoMes()">Separar ano e mês</button>
```

Lembrando que o `value` é uma string, e o resultado do `split` é um array de strings. Então meses anteriores a outubro terão o zero à esquerda (`02`, `05`, etc). Mas se quiser que sejam números (sem o zero à esquerda), basta trocar para:

```js
let [ano, mes] = document.getElementById('month').value.split('-').map(v => parseInt(v));
```

---

Outra forma é pegar o valor como uma data (um objeto `Date`), usando `valueAsDate` em vez de `value`, assim seria possível obter o mês e ano usando os *getters*, como foi sugerido nos comentários. **Mas tem uma "pegadinha"**, veja:

```js
function mostrarValue() {
    var date = document.getElementById('month').valueAsDate;
    console.log(date.toString()); // data no fuso do browser
    console.log(date.toISOString()); // data em UTC
}
```

```html
<input type="month" id="month" />
<button onclick="mostrarValue()">Mostrar value</button>
```

A saída pode variar de acordo com o fuso horário que está configurado no seu browser (que *geralmente* é o mesmo do sistema operacional). No caso, o meu está configurado no Horário de Brasília, e eu escolhi o mês de maio de 2022. A saída foi:

```
Sat Apr 30 2022 21:00:00 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time)
2022-05-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

Pois é. Ao converter o valor do campo (que só tem mês e ano) para uma data, ele preenche os campos faltantes com valores default (no caso, dia 1 e horário meia-noite), mas tudo isso em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Só que 1 de maio à meia-noite em UTC equivale a 30 de abril às 21h no horário de Brasília. Então se eu usar `getMonth()` para obter o mês, não necessariamente será o mesmo que foi preenchido. Felizmente existe `getUTCMonth()` para obter o mês em UTC. Portanto, seria algo assim:

```js
function mostrarValue() {
    let datainput = document.getElementById('month').valueAsDate;
    let mes = datainput.getUTCMonth() + 1;
    let ano = datainput.getUTCFullYear();
    console.log(mes, ano);
}
```

```html
<input type="month" id="month" />
<button onclick="mostrarValue()">Mostrar value</button>
```

Lembrando que em JavaScript os meses são indexados em zero (ver mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405998/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/416172/112052)), ou seja, janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc. Por isso precisei somar 1 no código acima.

Lembrando que o código acima retorna os valores numéricos, portanto valores menores que 10 não terão o zero à esquerda. Se deseja que tenha, teria que gerar uma string com `mes.toString().padStart(2, '0')`.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar o `.split()` para separar a string pelo '/' da data.

A função `.split()` retornará um array, no qual o índice 0 será o mês e o índice 1 será o ano.

Exemplo:

```
let datainput = document.getElementById('month').value;

let dataString = datainput.split('/') // Retornará ['09', '2022']
let mes = dataString[0]
let ano = dataStrig[1]
```